# If I remove my apple ID account on my Iphone 4s, does it delete the data on iCloud on that device only?

Tags: icloud, iphone, apple-id

If I remove my apple ID account on my Iphone 4s, does it delete the data on iCloud on that device only? I already have an Iphone 5s which is using the same apple ID. And planning to sell my Iphone 4s. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: If you're selling the phone, turn off findmyiphone and then reset (clear the memory). https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351

Answer (score 1):

Removing your Apple ID account from your iPhone should have no affect on the data stored in iCloud. You can safely sign out of iCloud and related services from your iPhone. In doing that, read the prompts to confirm that you are not as they look rather ominous at times, but should only be telling you that data will be removed from *the phone*.

Comment: I won't -1 this, as it ***is*** strictly the answer to the question; but Tyson's comment is actually better advice - remove from find my iPhone, then totally reset.